# Solidity uses with technology to write code

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I wanted to start learning developing smart contract and i just heard of solidity terminology. 
Will be helpful if any link or docs link to go through

I have gone through some online learning courses but not much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good places to start:

- Ethereum.org https://ethereum.org/developers
- CryptoZombies: https://cryptozombies.io
- Truffle Pet Shop tutorial: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop
- Ethernaut security game: https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com
- OpenZeppelin SDK https://docs.openzeppelin.com/sdk/2.5/first

You can ask questions about using OpenZeppelin on the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com

Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin